# Compile Medooze - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, linux, video, implementation, mixer

I`m trying to install Medooze but I faced with lots of problem!
I followed step by step by this instruction http://www.medooze.com/products/media-mixer-server/installation.aspx
most of them installed with out error until step 9. when I use "make" there are bunch of errors, I fixed many of them but when I trying to fix this one, I cant.

> /usr/local/src/medooze/mcu/src/gsm/gsm.h:34:32: fatal error: GSM3CircularBuffer.h: No such file or directory
>    #include
>   GSM3CircularBuffer.h>
>
> compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [audio.o] Error 1

I was trying to make this file manually but it doesnt work.
Do you have any suggestion?

Update:

I solved it by downloading `libgsm1-dev` in `/usr/local/src/` path

but now I see this error:

> In file included from /usr/local/src/medooze/mcu/src/cef/Browser.h:11:0,
>                    from test/cef.cpp:2:
>
> /usr/local/src/medooze/mcu/src/cef/include/cef_app.h:42:30: fatal error: include/cef_base.h: No such file or directory
>    #include "include/cef_base.h"
>                                 ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [test/cef.o] Error 1

Comment: try run this with sudo user ?

Comment: I`m trying with root. is that the answer?!